# Getting error : The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Guid' and 'System.String'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

This is My Expression Class

```
        public static class ExpressionBuilder
    {
        private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
        private static MethodInfo startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        private static MethodInfo endsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });


        public static Expression<Func<T,
        bool>> GetExpression<T>(IList<Filter> filters)
        {
            if (filters.Count == 0)
                return null;

            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
            Expression exp = null;

            if (filters.Count == 1)
                exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]);
            else if (filters.Count == 2)
                exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]);
            else
            {
                while (filters.Count > 0)
                {
                    var f1 = filters[0];
                    var f2 = filters[1];

                    if (exp == null)
                        exp = GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]);
                    else
                        exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0], filters[1]));

                    filters.Remove(f1);
                    filters.Remove(f2);

                    if (filters.Count == 1)
                    {
                        exp = Expression.AndAlso(exp, GetExpression<T>(param, filters[0]));
                        filters.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);
        }

        private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter)
        {
            MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
            ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);

            switch (filter.Operation)
            {
                case Op.Equals:
                    return Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(search.RetrieveGuid), typeof(object)), typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"))), constant);

                case Op.GreaterThan:
                    return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);

                case Op.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);

                case Op.LessThan:
                    return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);

                case Op.LessThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);

                case Op.Contains:
                    return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant);

                case Op.StartsWith:
                    return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, constant);

                case Op.EndsWith:
                    return Expression.Call(member, endsWithMethod, constant);
            }

            return null;
        }

        private static BinaryExpression GetExpression<T>
        (ParameterExpression param, Filter filter1, Filter filter2)
        {
            Expression bin1 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter1);
            Expression bin2 = GetExpression<T>(param, filter2);

            return Expression.AndAlso(bin1, bin2);
        }
    }
```

when i generate Expression by this code

```
 delegExpFilters = EntityExpression.ExpressionBuilder.GetExpression<Contact>(domainFilter).Compile();
```

my domainFilter Contains a list records with 
Property field name ,operator, and its value and my field is GUID

when i call GetExpression it gives me error 
The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Guid' and 'System.String'

Comment: The error is telling you your exact problem.  Somewhere you are comparing a `System.Guid` to a `System.String`.  To compare the two you will have to convert a Guid to a string: `someGuid.ToString()` or convert a string to a Guid: `Guid.Parse(stringGuid)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are not converting filter value (which is string) to appropriate type:

```
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
```

Consider you have filter for integer property named `Amount`:

```
var filter = new Filter {
   PropertyName = "Amount",
   Operation = Op.GreaterThan,
   Value = "42"
};
```

Your code will generate expression which equivalent of following code

```
contract.Amount > "42"
```

Such integer comparison with string is not allowed.

---

You should get property type and convert filter value to that type. Here are the steps:

1. Get type converter for property type
2. Check whether it can convert string to property type
3. Do conversion (that will return property value as `object`
4. Create cast expression to convert property value from `object` to property type

Here is code of `GetExpression` method

```
var member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);
var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)member.Member).PropertyType;
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyType); // 1

if (!converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string))) // 2
   throw new NotSupportedException();

var propertyValue = converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(filter.Value); // 3
var constant = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
var valueExpression = Expression.Convert(constant, propertyType); // 4
```

You should use this value expression instead of your constant expression in binary expressions which you are returning. E.g.:

```
case Op.LessThan:
    return Expression.LessThan(member, valueExpression);
case Op.Equal:
    return Expression.Equal(member, valueExpression);
// etc
```

For equality you should use binary expression as well. And now filter for `Amount` will be translated into

```
 contract.Amount > (int)42
```

Comment: cant understand its very difficult for me , if you can change my Expression class then easy for me

Comment: @FrazZaki put this code into `GetExpression` method. Replace constants with valueExpression and think about unsupported conversion handling. Just read everything carefully.

Comment: converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string) returns true but the converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(filter.Value) method throws FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.